# "Slide to Type " like iOS floating keyboard in macOS?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, ios, keyboard, ipados

Is there any software that can use iOS floating keyboard in macOS?

I want to type using only the trackpad , use  "Slide to Type " in my trackpad to typing:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There's similar, accessible from the Input Menu in the menu bar, once you enable that in System Prefs > Keyboard > Input Sources

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you , but this does not support "Slide to Type "

Comment: That wasn't in your original question. I've no way to test 'slide to type' as I have no Mac with a trackpad.